# How to deregister a function from SignalR client in angular11?

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr.client

I am using @microsoft/signalr package installed in Angular 11 application. I have called below init() method available in signalr.service.ts in multiple components(orders.component.ts and sales.component.ts). When I move to orders component, SignalR init() method called and receive the messages. Then I will try to move away from orders component to sales component, same init() method() will be called once again and will receive the messages from the SignalR hub. I have called hub's off method to deregister the hub method while leaving from the component. Even after calling hub's off method, I am getting below warning message while moving to orders component and receiving the messages from the SignalR hub. Could you please help me on this issue?

**Warning Message:** Warning: No client method with the name 'notifyresult' found.

**signalr.service.ts:**

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

orderMessages: Subject<any> = new Subject();
saleMessages: Subject<any> = new Subject();
     
private getConnectionInfo(): Observable<SignalRConnectionInfo> {
   return this.http.get<SignalRConnectionInfo>(environment.signalRUrl);
}
    
init() {
   this.getConnectionInfo().subscribe(info => {
      let options = {
           accessTokenFactory: () => info.accessToken
      };
   this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .withUrl(info.url, options)
       .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 1000, 5000, null])
       .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)        
       .build();
   this.hubConnection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
   this.hubConnection.off('notifyresult');
   this.hubConnection.on('notifyresult', (data: any) => {
   if(data == "Orders") {
       this.orderMessages.next(data);
   }
   else {
       this.saleMessages.next(data);
   }
  });
});
}
```

**orders.component.ts:**

```
public orderMessageSubscription: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.signalRService.init();
  this.orderMessageSubscription = this.signalRService.orderMessages.subscribe(message => {
  });
}
 
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.signalRService.hubConnection?.off("notifyresult");
   this.orderMessageSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**sales.component.ts:**

```
public saleMessageSubscription: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.signalRService.init();
  this.saleMessageSubscription= this.signalRService.saleMessages.subscribe(message => {
  });
}
 
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.signalRService.hubConnection?.off("notifyresult");
   this.saleMessageSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```